# GPG key - utf-8 convert to ascii

Tags: cassandra

I needed to convert a gpg key for Cassandra. I downloaded it
wget https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS

If you want to convert with the command:
iconv -f utf-8 -t us-ascii//TRANSLIT KEYS > KEYS_ascii
I received the following output:
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 169653

After removing the lines containing invalid characters from the file (the last one in the name Rene):
sed -i '/E0B7D6BE/d' KEYS
I was able to successfully convert the file as needed

Can I ask you to correct the file, please? https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS
So that it doesn't contain any wrong characters?

Regards. Robert